# AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'load' in python

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to run a simple code here and I am getting this error. I am using Python3 on pycharm env.

```
Code:
import pickle


with open('labels.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

Is there a workaround to open and view what is inside this file? Thanks.

Comment: Do not save your code as `pickle.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was able to fix it by running this code on the python3 terminal.